# How to select all faces between selected edges

Tags: faces, edges, selection-tools

Is it possible to select all faces between selected edges in Blender ?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/94591/how-can-i-quickly-select-all-faces-surrounded-by-4-vertices-or-4-edges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2.7x Spacebar > Select loop inner-region.

2.8 F3 > Select loop inner-region.